# Triangle won't rotate

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

So I followed this tutorial from Google: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html

The triangle is supposed to rotate in response to touch events, but nothing happens.  It also didn't rotate in the earlier step when it was supposed to rotate on its own.  Not sure what the problem is.  I just copied their code.

The whole project is only two files:

HelloOpenGLES20Activity.java

```
package com.opengl.es20;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class HelloOpenGLES20Activity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
        // as the ContentView for this Activity
        mGLView = new HelloOpenGLES20SurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // The following call pauses the rendering thread.
        // If your OpenGL application is memory intensive,
        // you should consider de-allocating objects that
        // consume significant memory here.
        mGLView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // The following call resumes a paused rendering thread.
        // If you de-allocated graphic objects for onPause()
        // this is a good place to re-allocate them.
        mGLView.onResume();
    }
}

class HelloOpenGLES20SurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
    private HelloOpenGLES20Renderer mRenderer;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;

    public HelloOpenGLES20SurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        // set the mRenderer member
        mRenderer = new HelloOpenGLES20Renderer();
        setRenderer(mRenderer);

        // Render the view only when there is a change
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
        // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
        // interested in events where the touch position changed.

        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                float dy = y - mPreviousY;

                // reverse direction of rotation above the mid-line
                if (y > getHeight() / 2) {
                  dx = dx * -1 ;
                }

                // reverse direction of rotation to left of the mid-line
                if (x < getWidth() / 2) {
                  dy = dy * -1 ;
                }

                mRenderer.mAngle += (dx + dy) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;
                requestRender();
        }

        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;
        return true;
    } 
}
```

HelloRendererOpenGLES20Renderer.java

```
package com.opengl.es20;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class HelloOpenGLES20Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private FloatBuffer triangleVB;
    private final String vertexShaderCode = 
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;  \n" +
            "attribute vec4 vPosition; \n" +
            "void main(){              \n" +
            " gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition; \n" +
            "}                         \n";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode = 
            "precision mediump float;  \n" +
                    "void main(){              \n" +
                    " gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.63671875, 0.76953125, 0.22265625, 1.0); \n" +
                    "}                         \n";
    private int mProgram;
    private int maPositionHandle;
    private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mMMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];

    public float mAngle;

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        initShapes();

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL program executables

        // get handle to the vertex shader's vPosition member
        maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // Prepare the triangle data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, triangleVB);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);

        // Create a rotation for the triangle
//        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
//        float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
        Matrix.setRotateM(mMMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        // Apply a ModelView Projection transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float ratio = (float) width/height;
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
        muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    private void initShapes(){

        float triangleCoords[] = {
            // X, Y, Z
            -0.5f, -0.25f, 0,
             0.5f, -0.25f, 0,
             0.0f,  0.559016994f, 0
        }; 

        // initialize vertex Buffer for triangle  
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                triangleCoords.length * 4); 
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());// use the device hardware's native byte order
        triangleVB = vbb.asFloatBuffer();  // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        triangleVB.put(triangleCoords);    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        triangleVB.position(0);            // set the buffer to read the first coordinate

    }

    private int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type); 

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Matrix.setRotateM(mMMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    // Apply a ModelView Projection transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
```

I believe this final multiplyMM is your problem. You are resetting your mMVPMatrix to be
mMVPMatrix = mProjMatrix * mVMatrix, and you are losing your model transformation matrix mMMatrix which would apply your rotation. Also, verify that mAngle is non-zero.